# Refresh Fragment after loading it

Tags: java, android, navigation, fragment, drawer

So I've recently got into Android programming and for a while I've been struggling with this problem. I use navigation drawer and got some fragments attached to it. But whenever I switch tabs/fragments, all variables are reset and I have to manually reset them again.

However, I would like if it were automatical. After fragment load -> refresh data from custom class..

This is my code of the fragment, but it crashes on nullpointerexception.

```
public class TimeFragment extends Fragment {

        private final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public TimeFragment(int sectionNumber) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            this.setArguments(args);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_time, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }


        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
            refreshFragment();
        }

        public void refreshFragment() {
            TextView text_first = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNS_Days);
            TextView text_second = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNS_Money);
            TextView text_third = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNS_Cigs);
            text_first.setText(String.format("%d", smokes.daysNotSmoked()));
            text_second.setText(String.format("%.1f", smokes.moneySaved()));
            text_third.setText(String.format("%d", smokes.cigsNotSmoked()));
        }

    }
```

and this is the default method that sets up fragments.

```
    @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment(position + 1);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new TimeFragment(position + 1);
            break;

    }
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();

}
```

Comment: Could you post the Logcat please? We don't know where the NPE occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I can use

```
@Override
public void onResume(){

}
```

on fragments. Solved it.